# Store Procedure in SAP HANA 2.0 insert from parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, hana

I want to create the store procedure but failed to create. my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "TESTING"."SCALAR_VARIABLE_EXAMPLE_INSERT" (IN paramin NVARCHAR(5000))
                LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
                SQL SECURITY INVOKER
                AS
BEGIN
/*****************************
                Write your procedure logic
 *****************************/
                DECLARE username varchar(20) := 'bobbyss';
                DECLARE description varchar(100);

                description := 'select JSON_VALUE('''||:paramin||''', ''$.description'') AS "desc" from DUMMY';

                INSERT INTO "TESTING"."USER" 
                VALUES (:username, :description);

END;
```

When I call this procedure, show SQL syntax error: incorrect syntax near "select"

how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, here is an working example:

```
create table test_user (username nvarchar(20), description nvarchar(100));
CREATE PROCEDURE SCALAR_VARIABLE_EXAMPLE_INSERT (IN paramin NVARCHAR(5000))
                LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
                SQL SECURITY INVOKER
                AS
BEGIN
/*****************************
                Write your procedure logic
 *****************************/
                DECLARE username varchar(20) := 'bobbyss';
                DECLARE description varchar(100);

                select JSON_VALUE(:paramin, '$.description') into description from DUMMY;

                INSERT INTO test_user 
                VALUES (:username, :description);

END;

call SCALAR_VARIABLE_EXAMPLE_INSERT('{"description":"Test Description..."}');
select * from test_user;
```

Comment: the error show: Could not execute 'call "TESTING".SCALAR_VARIABLE_EXAMPLE_INSERT()'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [1281]: wrong number or types of parameters in call: PARAMIN is not bound: line 1 col 16 (at pos 15)